# Add Unity-style HUD to XFCE?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, unity

The Linux distro TROMjaro, based on Manjaro, offers a HUD feature. This feature is similar to the HUD feature of Ubuntu Unity, allowing you to search through the menu items of an application. TROMjaro offers this feature on the XFCE desktop.

*Does anyone know what package or project is used to accomplish this?* I would like to add the HUD feature to an XFCE desktop on distros other than TROMjaro.

If anyone knows what software is used to accomplish this please link to the landing page or installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jamcnaughton/hud-menu

3 months late but its probably using this or something similar..